# finding an inner product so that matrix is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the endomorphisms

$$A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2i & 3i\\
0 & 2 & i\\          
0 & 0 & 3
\end{matrix}
\right) \in Mat(3 \times 3, \mathbb C),
$$
and
$$B=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2i & 3i\\
0 & 2 & i\\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{matrix}
\right) \in Mat(3 \times 3, \mathbb C)
$$

I want to check whether there is an inner product on $\mathbb C^3$ so that A resp B is self-adjoint or not but I don't really have a clue how to do this. I thought it might have something to do with eigenvalues or finding an orthonormal basis (which is possible for the first matrix as there are three distinct eigenvalues) but I don't know how to handle the inner product.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was an inner product that satisfies your condition, then there would (as you noted) be an orthonormalbasis (w.r.t. this inner product) of eigenvectors for the respective matrix.

Let us call these eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Then, the inner product is uniquely determined, because each $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^3$ can be written as
$x = \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i v_i$ and $y = \sum_{i=1}^3 y_i v_i$, so that the inner product of $x,y$ is given by $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \overline{y_i}$.

In the opposite direction, by defining(!) the inner product by the above formula, any "Eigenbasis" of $\mathbb{C}^3$ yields an inner product for which $v_1, v_2, v_3$ is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. The corresponding matrix is then self-adjoint w.r.t. this inner product iff all eigenvalues are real.

Put short: Check if you matrices admit bases of eigenvectors with real eigenvalues. If this is the case, the inner product can be found as above. If not, there does not exist such an inner product.

This is the case for the first matrix, but not for the second.

Comment: Thanks so far. I can figure out what the "Eigenbasis" and the corresponding orthonormla basis is. But I do not understand how I get the inner product providing this?

Comment: Find the map that maps each $x \in \mathbb{C}^3$ to its coordinates in the disembodied

Comment: Find the map T that maps each $x \in \mathbb{C}^3$ to its coordinates in the eigenbasis, e.g. for $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (1,1)$ (I take $n=2$ for simplicity), we would map $x= (x_1, x_2)$ to $T(x) = (x_1, x_2 - x_1)$, because $x = x_1 v_1 + (x_2 - x_1) v_2$. Then your inner product is given by $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^3 (T(x))_i \overline{(T(y))_i}$. P.S.: Damn autocorrection on my tablet.

Comment: I finally got it:D Now I have problems to show that the inner product is positiv definite. I've got T(x)=(x_1 - 2ix_2 - (1 + (3i)/2))x_3, x_2 - ix_3, (1/2)x_3). Can you tell me why this is positve definite?

Comment: That essentially follows by construction. Because if $\langle x,x \rangle = 0$ this means $(T(x))_i = 0$ for all $i$. But because of $x = \sum_{i=1}^3 (T(x))_i v_i$, this implies $x=0$.